# Updating a Dataflow job from the rest API

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to programatically update a cloud DataFlow job by using the REST API as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/update)

I have a PubSub to BigQuery job and my end goal is to replace the BigQuery output table.

I've tried updating the current job with a new job by using the *replacedByJobId* field but always getting this error:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": 400,
>           "message": "(b7fd8310f1b85ccf): Could not modify workflow; invalid modifier value: 0",
>           "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
>       } }

Request body:

> {
>       "id": "*jobid*",
>       "projectId": "*projectId*",
>       "replacedByJobId = "*newJobId*", }

Is there another way to either replace a running job's parameters (OutputTable) or replace a running job with a new similar job?

Answer (score 1):

In order to update a job you also need to provide a compatible replacement job. Note that update is currently only supported using the Java SDK.

You can find documentation on updating using the Java SDK at: [Updating an Existing Pipeline: Launching Your Replacement Job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline#launching-your-replacement-job).

Comment: ah, I was afraid of this. So what I am trying to do is not possible from the REST API. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
java -jar pipeline/build/libs/pipeline-service-1.0.jar \
        --project=my-project \
        --zone=us-central1-f \
        --streaming=true \
        --stagingLocation=gs://my-bucket/tmp/dataflow/staging/ \
        --runner=DataflowPipelineRunner \
        --numWorkers=5 \
        --workerMachineType=n1-standard-2 \
        --jobName=ingresspipeline \
        --update
```

Comment: It's usually better to provide a bit of explanation for your answer alongside the code. As it is I'm not convinced this has anything to do with the question